# Crossing in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

Have anyone idea how to do a crossing in blender geometry nodes?I've made something like below but don have idea how to make faces in geometry nodes Thanks in advance.[image]

[image]

To be more specific I'd like to add red triangles for every vertices which has more then 2 neighbors like on picture below
[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "do a crossing"? What exactly should the mesh topology look like in this case? Can you show a concrete example of this?

Comment: Yes, result is marked on image red mesh. Something like that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRJl0uAnMZU